# PowerShell bad number recognition

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a simple program in which does something. However I have problem in this specific part of the code where user should input a number which would be processed afterwards:

```
do{
    $user = Read-Host "Input some number from 1 to 3"
       if($user -lt 1 -or $user -gt 3){
        echo "From 1 to 3, $user is too many"}
       else{ 
// do the right thing  }}
until(it's done)
```

But when user inputs number which start either with 1 or 2 on the start of the number (such as `1256`, `25698`, etc.), the exception does not trigger. It works on other numbers perfectly but these are bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're capturing $user as a string, and then testing it as a string-comparison (which succeeds with the conditions shown above).

If you specify the variable as `[int]$user`, it successfully checks the numbers starting with 1-3.

Example code:

```
do{
    [int]$user = Read-Host "Input a number from 1 to 3"
    if($user -lt 1 -or $user -gt 3) {
      echo "Please input a number between 1 and 3, $user is too high"
    }
    else { 
      Write-Host "$user is within bounds"  
    }
}
until($condition -eq $true)
```